# What happens to the sedimentation collected in water treatment plants?

Tags: water-resources, waste-water-treatment

The Washington DC water treatment plant appears to use sedimentation tanks for both treating water before consumption and for treating sewage that is then discharged.

My question: What happens to the sedimentation after it is collects? None of the articles that I have read discuss this.

It seems to me that the sediment in the water source won't necessarily be toxic, but I suspect that the sediment in the sewage contains a brew of toxic metals and organics. So does that need to be treated as toxic waste? Is the source sediment used for fertilizer, or is it just sent to a landfill? Is there an issue with dust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was part of a team of contractors to remove and spread the dried sediment from a water treatment facility - the sediment was a red cake/ powder and was spread on the fields as fertiliser.

Comment: Milwaukee WI sells it as Milorganite fertilizer . I filled a pick-up truck with it at a Cook Co ( Chicago IL) treatment plant. It  was free garden fertilizer, but it took some paint off the truck bed.  Interestingly , tomato seeds made it through the treatment ( decades ago).